# Display a comparison table

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a html table with each column displaying a company and each row has a feature that offers this company.

Let's say 
Company A has features 1,2,3 and features 8,9 optional. 
Company B has features 1,3 and features 7,8 optional. 
Company C has features 3,4 and features 9,10 optional.

```
      //A  B  C
//-------------
//1  |  Y  Y  X
//2  |  Y  X  X
//3  |  Y  Y  Y
//4  |  X  X  Y
//7  |  X  O  X
//8  |  O  O  X
//9  |  O  X  O
//10 |  X  X  O
```

I dont display features 5,6 because they are missing in all companies.

I want the table to display "fa-check"(Y) when the company contains the feature, "fa-times"(X) when is missing and input type="checkbox" when the feature is optional. Each optional feature has a price so the total price for a company is recalculated when is checked

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <!-- ko foreach : companies -->
        <th data-bind="text: name"></th>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach : UnionOfFeatures-->
    <tr>
        <!-- ko foreach : companies -->
        <td data-bind="if: mandatory"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
        <td data-bind="ifnot: mandatory"><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Checked"></td>
        @*<td data-bind="when is Missing"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></td>*@  
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function feature(id, mandatory) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.mandatory = ko.observable(mandatory);
}

function company(name, features) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.features = ko.observableArray(features);
}

var viewModel = function () {
    self.companies = ko.observableArray(
    [
      new company("Company 1", [
           new feature(1, true),
           new feature(2, true),
           new feature(3, true),
           new feature(8, false),
           new feature(9, false)
      ]),

      new company("Company 2", [
           new feature(1, true),
           new feature(3, true),
           new feature(7, false),
           new feature(8, false)
      ]),

      new company("Company 3", [
           new feature(3, true),
           new feature(4, true),
           new feature(9, false),
           new feature(10, false)
      ]),
    ]);


    self.UnionFeaturesIds = ko.computed(function () {   
        return 0; //????;
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: What is your actual question / problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `var self = this` inside your viewModel.

I've had a quick play with this, and I decided to do it in slightly different way. Feel free to change any of my code, I'm just having fun ;p

I've produced an array of all features, which I can always reference. Then I created a new helper logic inside each company that will loop through all features.

If a given feature is found, it's then added, otherwise we create a dummy object that we know is a missing feature (I've added ID of `-1`)

```js
var allFeatures = ko.observableArray();

function feature(id, mandatory) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = id;
  self.mandatory = ko.observable(mandatory);
}

function company(name, features) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = name;
  self.features = ko.observableArray(features);
}

var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.companies = ko.observableArray(
    [

      new company("Company 1", [
        new feature(1, true),
        new feature(2, true),
        new feature(3, true),
        new feature(8, false),
        new feature(9, false)
      ]),

      new company("Company 2", [
        new feature(1, true),
        new feature(3, true),
        new feature(7, false),
        new feature(8, false)
      ]),

      new company("Company 3", [
        new feature(3, true),
        new feature(4, true),
        new feature(9, false),
        new feature(10, false)
      ])
    ]);
  self.setFeatures = function(features) {
    var featuresToChange = features;
    var tempFeatures = [];
    // loop through all features, so we can create all rows in the HTML
    for (var i = 0; i < allFeatures().length; i++) {
      var currentFeature = featuresToChange()[i];

      // see if current feature exists in a given company
      var featureWithIdFound = ko.utils.arrayFirst(featuresToChange(), function(item) {
        return item.id === allFeatures()[i];
      });

      // if the feature was found, and we are currently looping through its ID, push it to temporary array
      if (featureWithIdFound !== null && featureWithIdFound.id === allFeatures()[i]) {
        tempFeatures.push(featureWithIdFound);
      } else {
        // otherwise push a feature that's missing, by giving it's negative ID
        tempFeatures.push(new feature(-1));
      }
    }
    // push to existing features array in that company
    featuresToChange(tempFeatures);
  }
  self.createAllFeaturesList = function() {
    var _allFeatures = [];
    // loop through all companies to get unique features
    for (var i = 0; i < self.companies().length; i++) {
      var curCompany = self.companies()[i];
      // push all unique items to temporary array called _allFeatures
      ko.utils.arrayFirst(curCompany.features(), function(item) {
        if (_allFeatures.indexOf(item.id) < 0 && item.id !== -1) {
          // only push items that don't exist in the array, so we don't end up with duplicated
          _allFeatures.push(item.id);
        }
      });
    }
    // sort IDs
    _allFeatures.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a > b ? 1 : -1
    });
    allFeatures(_allFeatures);

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.companies(), function(item) {
      // apply them to table
      self.setFeatures(item.features);
    });
  };
  // instantiate features
  self.createAllFeaturesList();
}



ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
.fa-check {
  color: green;
}
.fa-times {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: companies">
      <th data-bind="text: name"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: companies">
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody data-bind="foreach: features">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <i class="fa fa-check" data-bind="visible: mandatory"></i>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="visible: !mandatory() && id > 0"/>
                <i class="fa fa-times" data-bind="visible: id < 0"></i>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thank you .It's possible to make allFeatures array the union of three companies (without rows 5,6 becaure they are missing in all companies).

Comment: Do you mean is it possible to make `allFeatures` array populate dynamically during load time? Sure, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Did it help you? If yes, could you mark it as an answer please?